# ffmpeg pass through video including Dolby Video

Tags: ffmpeg

Given media that contains a video stream that includes Dolby Vision as one of the HDR metadata, how does one transcode the media and maintain the video stream as is (including the Dolby Vision and any other HDR metadata)?

Sample media `mediainfo` excerpt:

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5@High
HDR format                               : Dolby Vision, Version 1.0, dvhe.08.06, BL+RPU, HDR10 compatible / SMPTE ST 2094 App 4, Version 1, HDR10+ Profile B compatible
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
...
```

`-c:v:0 copy` drops the Dolby Vision metadata from this and retains only the latter HDR metadata.